# How can you tell if a C++ dynamic library in Visual Studio 2012 is managed or unmanaged?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2012

Maybe this will probably be a dumn question, but I can't figure this out. I know the difference betwee managed and unmanaged code, but I have gotten a C++.NET solution and I can't figure out whether a C++ project is managed or unmanaged.

I actually don't think that it is managed.

Looking at the properties, I can configure things like Use of MFC (=Use Standard Windows Libraries), Use of ATL, Configuration type (Dynamic Library), ...

The assembly is actually a wrap around unmanaged C code (lib) with one cpp exporting C functions to C# managed code.

Comment: Tried to use the Intermediate Language Disassembler, ildasm, to look inside the assembly and it says me that it has no valid CLR. So it's clearly unmanaged...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Managed" C++ projects are actually **C++/CLI** projects which use the .NET **Common Language Runtime  (CLR)**. This is expressed in Visual Studio with a `/clr` in the compilation switches.

See [/clr (Common Language Runtime Compilation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s.aspx) on MSDN for details.

Note also that Microsoft informs you that "it is even possible to decide between managed and unmanaged compilation on a function-by-function basis within the same file". See [Mixed (Native and Managed) Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0w2664k.aspx) also on MSDN for even more details on that.

Comment: Ok, seen it. Switching to /clr is as straightforward it seems. Getting a whole lot of errors when doing so.

Comment: I didn't say that you can take _any_ valid C++ program and just throw it to Microsoft and mark it with the `/clr` switch so that it is automatically "managed code". Maybe you can ask separate questions about the errors you get when you try to use `/clr`, after having done some research about it.

Comment: @LievenCardoen You simply asked *How can you tell if a C++ dynamic library in Visual Studio 2012 is managed or unmanaged?* and I believe you have answers to that question

Comment: Yes, indeed, no panic, that was just my question, thx. Can't mark both of you as correct though.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19770608/96780) is actually more specific to your question, so I think you should accept that one instead :)

Answer (score 4):

Look at the **Configuration Properties** node of the project properties dialog. Within that section there is an item named **Common Language Runtime Support**. An unmanaged project will have the value **No Common Language Runtime Support**, otherwise the project is managed.

This setting corresponds to the [/clr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k8d11d4s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) compiler option.